# Product Pictures (Align)

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images

I have images that are not aligned despite a Python script I've created that Trims and Resizes the images (works on Watches and Jewelry and other standardized items). This is happening when items like bags have one image with the shoulder strap up and others with the shoulder strap down, which occupies different ratios of horizontal and vertical dimensions.

Aside from retaking the images so they are somewhat standardized (e.g all straps down), is there a way to make the images aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer. One needs to trim the image, remove the bottom border and resize the image to one common resolution across the category type with the bottom border removed.